# Prove that matrix $A = U^{-1}HU$ is Hermitian

Tags: matrices, linear-algebra

This is one of my Mathematica Assignment problems. 
Assuming that the matrix $H$ is Hermitian and the matrix $U$ is unitary, prove that the  matrix $A = U^{-1}HU$ is Hermitian. 
Can someone help? I'm unable to do it!

Comment: I believe you meant to post this on [math.se]. This site is for the software program [_Mathematica_](https://www.wolfram.com/), not [mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics).

Comment: The definitions of Unitary and Hermitian matrices are $U^{-1} = U^*$ and $H=H^*$. You just need to check that $A^* = A$. The identity $(MN)^*=N^*M^*$ will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $H$ satisfies ${}^t \overline{H} = H$ and $U$ satisfies ${}^t \overline{U} U = I_{n}$, which means that $\left( {}^t \overline{U} \right)^{-1} = U$. Consider ${}^t \overline{A}$, you have

$${}^t \overline{A} = {}^t \overline{U} {}^t \overline{H} {}^t \overline{U^{-1}} $$

Using the previous equalities, you get :

$${}^t \overline{A} = U^{-1} H U = A$$

So $A$ is hermitian.